# Vertex cover of size k, prove this graph is (k+1)-colorable

Tags: coloring

Let G be a graph that has a vertex cover of size l. Prove that G is (l+1)-colorable.

This is supposed to be true. But I'm confused since a vertex cover can be the cover of the entire graph G. So then if it covers l vertices (all vertices in G), then how would it be (l+1)-colorable?

I feel like I'm missing something or interpreting this wrong. But any clarification would help me a lot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be a vertex cover of size $k$. Color each vertex of $C$ with a different color, and color every remaining vertex of $G$ with a $(k+1)$-st color. Every edge has at least one endpoint in $C$, so no edge has endpoints of the same color. If every vertex of $G$ is in $C$, you’ve actually used only $k$ colors, but that certainly means that $k+1$ colors suffice, i.e., that $G$ is $(k+1)$-colorable.